# Woocommerce remove buy button in individual product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I've been able to set enquire for price to show when I don't list a price in woocommerce which would be amazing except when you try to add the product to cart it shows as free.  Is there a way to just remove the buy button from the product pages individually?  I'm also running into a similar problem with variable products.  Buy is there, but it doesn't actually add to cart, so it would be nice to just remove the button on the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I was able to answer my own question and decided to post my findings here incase anyone else comes across this issue.
After looking in depth at several of the files on the ftp, I was able to identify where the buy button is inserted on the content-single-product.php.  Before the code that was set to insert the button, I added some restrictions so that the buy button would only appear if there was an actual price.
I did something similar to remove the buy button on products that come as a variation (because we want this to run as more of an enquire for price).

Answer (score 1):

A custom page template could work in this situation - check out the help files over at woothemes for more info.